# Determining Equivalence Relation on $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Alright, I have a homework problem which I have researched, read up on and I (think) solved. I just need someone to either confirm my answer (and re-affirm my knowledge) or explain why I am wrong.

Here is the question:

- Is $\{(x,y) | |x|=|y|\}$ an equivalence relation on $\Bbb{Z}$?

I believe this is true. I created a sample relation (is this the correct term?)
consisting of $\{(3,3),(2,2),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1)\}$ just to help my visualize the question.

From what I understand, and what I can see in my example, the proposed realation is
Reflexive, Symmetric, and Transative. Am I correct?

Comment: The relation is an equivalence relation. You should *prove it*. Note that negative numbers are important here, so your example is not informative. There are three things to prove. (i) Reflexive: Is it true that $|x|=|x|$ for all $x$? Of course it is. (ii) Symmetric; (iii) Transitive. It's your turn.

Comment: Thank you I will try a proof and post my results.

Comment: Ok here is a draft of a Proof for Symmetry: Let x = -4. Then because of `|x|=|y|`, my ordered pair would be (-4,4). Then to test for Symmetry I would have to prove that (4,-4) is part of the relation, correct? And becasue |4|=|-4|, we can prove that it is in fact part of the Relation. Therefore [the realtion] on set Z is proven to be Symmetric. Is that correct?

Comment: No response? I have added a proof with an example element and also a proof of arbitrary elements (seen in the comments on the answer posted by Bill)

Comment: @Adam By definition a relation $R$ is symmetric iff $\ (x,y)\in R \iff (y,x)\in R.\,$ To prove that, it suffices to show that for any $\,x,y\,$ we  have $\,(x,y)\in R\,\Rightarrow\, (y,x)\in R.$ A proof  must say *precisely* how that inference is obtained. I do not see that above.

Comment: I can read the symbols that you are typing, but I am clearly missing the core concept of how your inference is obtained. I thought I demonstrated it once with arbitrary elements and then once with actual elements from set Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice way to proceed - one that works quite generally.  Notice that $\rm\,x\sim y\,$ iff $\rm\,x\,$ and $\rm\,y\,$ have equal $ $  magnitude: $\rm\ \ x\sim y {\overset{\ def}{\color{#c00}\iff}} f(x) = f(y)\ $ for $\rm\:f(x) = \rm\,|x|.$

Now it is straightforward to prove that any relation of the above form is an equivalence relation.

More generally, suppose $\rm\ u\sim v\ \smash[t]{\overset{\ def}{\color{#c00}\iff}}\, f(u) \approx f(v)\ $ for a function $\rm\,f\,$ and equivalence relation $\,\approx.\, \ $ Then the equivalence relation $\rm\color{#0a0}{properties\ (E)}\,$  of $\,\approx\,$ transport (pullback) to $\,\sim\,$ along $\rm\,f$ as follows

- reflexive  $\rm\quad\ \color{#0a0}{(E)}\Rightarrow f(v) \approx f(v)\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\:v\sim v$
- symmetric  $\rm\,\ u\sim v\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\ f(u) \approx f(v)\:\color{#0a0}{\overset{(E)}\Rightarrow}\:f(v)\approx f(u)\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\:v\sim u$
- transitive $\rm\ \ \ u\sim v,\, v\sim w\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\: f(u)\approx f(v),\,f(v)\approx f(w)\:\color{#0a0}{\overset{(E)}\Rightarrow}\:f(u)\approx f(w)\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow u\sim w$

Such relations are called *(equivalence) kernels*. One calls $\, \sim\,$ the $\,(\approx)\,$ *kernel* of $\rm\,f.$

Yours is the special case when $\,\approx\,$ is the equivalence relation of *equality*.

Comment: I'm going to be honest here and say that your answer is beyond me. My book either doesnt present the definitions of reflexive, symmetric and transitive with those symbols or I just haven't gotten to that point in my course. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: I found this list of logic symbols [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) and it's helping me decipher your post. I love a good challenge lol.

Comment: I have deciphered the ⇔ symbol to mean logical equivalence in this case, is that correct? And the ~ symbol is just being used to separate ordered pairs, such as a comma is used to do so when written is this fashion (1,1) is that correct? Not all of the symbols you have used appear in the wikipedia list of logical symbols, and every tutorial and book I can find seem to use different symbols quite frequently. Can you point me to a list of the symbols you have chosen please?

Comment: @AdamJ Since  $\,\approx\,$ is an equivalence relation, it satisfies the equivalence relation properties, i.e. it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. For easy reference denote these properties of $\,\approx\,$ by $\,\rm \color{#0a0}{(E)},$ short for $\rm\color{#0a0}E$quivalence. The first bullet says this: $\,\rm \color{#0a0}{(E)}$ implies that $\rm\,f\,$ is reflexive, i.e. $\rm\,f(v)\approx f(v).\,$ In turn, this implies that $\,\rm v\sim v\,$ by the $\,\rm\color{#c00}{definition}$ of the relation $\,\sim.\,$ which states  that $\,\rm u\sim v\ \ \color{#c00}{iff}\ \ \rm f(u)\approx f(v).$

Comment: @AdamJ Yes, the logical symbols used are the standard symbols from the Wikipedia list. Just as for equality, equivalence relations are often denoted infix. For example, if we have an equivalence relation  $\,\rm R \subseteq \Bbb Z^2$ then $\rm\,(a,b)\in  R$ is often denoted $\rm\,a\,R\, b,\,$ or $\,a\sim b\,$ or $\,a\approx b\, $using the common symbols $\,\sim\,$ and $\,\approx\,$ often used to name equivalence relations, analogous to equality notation  $\,a = b.\,$ One thinks of equivalence relations as *generalized equality* relations, so one chooses notation that promotes that analogy.

Comment: @AdamJ Typo alert: in my first comment it should say $\,\approx\,$ is reflexive, not $\rm\,f.\,$ If anything else is not clear let me know and I can elaborate more.

Comment: Thank you for the symbols explanation! It was very helpful.

Comment: I realize that you have already posted quite a bit, and I hate to ask more of you, but I posted a prrof in the comments section of my OP, and was hoping that you could validate that it was correct/incorrect?  `André Nicolas` seems to have dissapeared.

Comment: @Adam The proof is a special case of that in the answer, with $\rm\,f(x) = |x|,\,$ and $\,\approx\,$ being equality $\,=\,$ e.g. for symmetry:  $\rm\,\ u\sim v\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\ |u| = |v|\:\color{#0a0}{\overset{(E)}\Rightarrow}\:|v| = |u|\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\:v\sim u\ \ $

Comment: So in the case of my original problem, If I have x = -3, then I would run that input through the function of |x|=|y|, and then I would end up with |3|=|3| so 3R3. Do I correctly understand how functions work? Specifiacally the |x|=|y| function in my problem? It just takes one input and then operates on it, then returns an output, correct? Am I crazy? I have an A+ in this course but the chapter on fucntions has just side swiped me!

Comment: Also, sperate from my previous post, I believe I have written an acceptable proof. I also believe that I am butchering proper symbology. For my Original Problem, It can be proven to be reflexive: |x|=|x|. It can be proven to be Symmetric: (|x|,|y|),(|y|,|x|) since |x|=|y|, which we know from the original problem, and we can prove it to be Transative: (|x|,|y|),(|y|,|z|),(|x|,|z|) which can also deduce from the original problem since we know that |x|=|y|, therefore if |y|=|x| we know that |x| must also = |z|

Comment: Does the proof I just posted make sense or I am I just spewing rubbish?

Comment: @Adam Any correct proof must involve *all* of the inferences (arrows) I gave in my answer - just as in the example I gave in the comment above showing symmetry. While you don't have to write those inferences symbolically with arrows, they do need to be *explicitly* mentioned for the proof to be complete. So you cannot just simply say $\,|x| = |x|.\,$ Compare to my proof, which derives reflexivity using *two* inferences (arrows)